# Are Kotlin object/singleton's methods synchronized?

Tags: android, kotlin

Does it make any sense to add the `@Synchronized` annotation to an object's methods to make them atomic or it isn't needed?

For example:

```
object Singleton {

    var field1: Int = 0
        private set

    var field2: Int = 0
        private set

    @Synchronized fun updateFields(f1: Int, f2: Int) {
        field1 = f1
        field2 = f2
    }

}
```

I want to ensure that all the fields are updated when I read them from other objects. Should I keep the `@Synchronized` annotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to achieve [`@Synchronized`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) semantics you need to add it explicitly - as in your example.

The `object Singleton {}` is no different in this matter from an object created with e.g. `val obj = Singleton()`.

One other way to ensure the fields are in sync is to model it explicitly e.g.:

```
object Singleton {
    @Volatile var state = State(0, 0)

    val field1: Int get() = state.field1
    val field2: Int get() = state.field2

    data class State(val field1: Int, val field2: Int)
}
```

And use `Singleton.state = Singleton.state.copy(field2 = 3)` to update the value. This obviously does not behave exactly the same as `@Synchronized` but is more explicit on the caller side that the values are to be in sync.

Comment: Thank you @miensol.
But if my example (with the annotation) is right, I will leave it like that, because yours would complicate the readability of the code when having a lot of fields.

Comment: @nitrico This was just a suggestion. Note that `val field1: Int get() = state.field1` are redundant in my example so even with lots of fields there would be little difference in terms of code size from your example.

Comment: But they should be in two places (the singleton itself and the internal class). 
Anyway, I've asked because I read that [singletons are thread-safe in Kotlin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179793/are-kotlins-singletons-thread-safe) but didn't know if that means what I try to achieve.

Comment: @nitrico 'Kotlin "object" is thread-safe by construction' is what the answer says - that is: creating the singleton object instance is thread safe.