# Safe re-initialization of variables inside Kotlin object

Tags: android, kotlin, initialization, thread-safety

I want to reinitialize *Retrofit* and *OkHttp* instances in case of some errors, like this, for example:

```
try {
    response = ApiFactory.apiInstance?.getData().execute()
} catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
    ApiFactory.apiInstance.resetApiInstanceWithNetworkClient()
}
```

My question, is this code a thread-safe in Kotlin (I have read that [Kotlin "object" is thread-safe by construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179793/are-kotlins-singletons-thread-safe)), or should I add some synchronized-blocks here?

```
object ApiFactory {

    var networkClientInstance: OkHttpClient? = null
    get() {
        return if (field == null) {
            buildClientInstance()
        } else {
            field
        }
    }

    var apiInstance: RestApiService? = null
    get() {
        return if (field == null) {
            buildRetrofit()
        } else {
            field
        }
    }

    fun resetApiInstanceWithNetworkClient() {
        apiInstance = null
        networkClientInstance = null
    }

    private fun buildClientInstance(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .callTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .connectionPool(ConnectionPool(0, 1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
                .build()
    }

    private fun buildRetrofit(): RestApiService {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("...")
                .client(networkClientInstance!!)
                .build()
                .create(RestApiService::class.java)
    }

}
```

Comment: perhaps a better question would be why are you trying to do this ? what is the problem you'd be solving with this ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody, we have a lot of SocketTimeoutExceptions in Crashlytics, probably it is connected with [This issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3974), and I want to try to re-initialize the network client when this exception happens.