# Coroutine Thread Safety with Retrofit

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have still a little bit of trouble putting all information together about the thread-safety of using coroutines to launch network requests.

Let's say we have following use-case, there is a list of users we get and for each of those users, I will do some specific check which has to run over a network request to the API, giving me some information back about this user.

The userCheck happens inside a library, which doesn't expose suspend functions but rather still uses a callback.
Inside of this library, I have seen code like this to launch each of the network requests:

```
internal suspend fun <T> doNetworkRequest(request: suspend () -> Response<T>): NetworkResult<T> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val response = request.invoke()
            ...
```

According to the documentation, Dispatchers.IO can use multiple threads for the execution of the code, also the request function is simply a function from a Retrofit API.

So what I did is to launch the request for each user, and use a single resultHandler object, which will add the results to a list and check if the length of the result list equals the length of the user list, if so, then all userChecks are done and I know that I can do something with the results, which need to be returned all together.

```
val userList: List<String>? = getUsers()
val userCheckResultList = mutableListOf<UserCheckResult>()
val handler = object : UserCheckResultHandler {
                  override fun onResult(
                        userCheckResult: UserCheckResult?
                  ) {
                        userCheckResult?.let {
                            userCheckResultList.add(
                                it
                            )
                        }
                        if (userCheckResultList.size == userList?.size) {
                            doSomethingWithResultList()
                            print("SUCCESS")
                        }
                    }
                }

userList?.forEach {
    checkUser(it, handler)
}
```

My question is: Is this implementation thread-safe? As far as I know, Kotlin objects should be thread safe, but I have gotten feedback that this is possibly not the best implementation :D

But in theory, even if the requests get launched asynchronous and multiple at the same time, only one at a time can access the lock of the thread the result handler is running on and there will be no race condition or problems with adding items to the list and comparing the sizes.

Am I wrong about this?
Is there any way to handle this scenario in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are executing multiple request in parallel - it's not. `List` is not thread safe. But it's simple fix for that. Create a `Mutex` object and then just wrap your operation on list in lock, like that:

```kotlin
val lock = Mutex()
val userList: List<String>? = getUsers()
val userCheckResultList = mutableListOf<UserCheckResult>()
val handler = object : UserCheckResultHandler {
                  override fun onResult(
                        userCheckResult: UserCheckResult?
                  ) {
                        lock.withLock {
                            userCheckResult?.let {
                                userCheckResultList.add(
                                    it
                                )
                            }
                            if (userCheckResultList.size == userList?.size) {
                                doSomethingWithResultList()
                                print("SUCCESS")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

userList?.forEach {
    checkUser(it, handler)
}
```

I have to add that this whole solution seems very hacky. I would go completely other route. Run all of your requests wrapping those in `async { // network request }` which will return `Deferred` object. Add this object to some list. After that wait for all of those deferred objects using `awaitAll()`. Like that:

```kotlin
val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()
userList?.forEach {
   // i assume checkUser is suspendable here
   jobs += async { checkUser(it, handler) }
}

// wait for all requests
jobs.awaitAll()

// After that you can access all results like this:
val resultOfJob0 = jobs[0].getCompleted()
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer! The proposed solution does look much nicer, but the assumption of checkUser being suspendable isn't right, which made me go for the other hacky way. This function does use coroutines under the hood but doesn't expose suspend functions because of interoperability with Java.

Comment: @Igor Oh, ok, so the version with lock might be solution for you :)

Comment: One thing is just left unclear for me: If a Kotlin object is thread-safe, even though I launch multiple requests simultaneously, only one at the time should be able to trigger the callback, or am I wrong? And if only one at the time triggers the callback and the code within the onResult function, why would it make adding objects to the list not thread safe? - or shortly put: if the list is not written to from the coroutine itself, but rather from the thread safe object, how come I still need the lock?

Comment: @Igor I'm not sure where did you get then info that "Kotlin object is thread-safe". No object is thread-safe by default. Here you have callback that can and probably will be called in parallel since requests are run in IO dispatcher. There are some build-in classes in kotlin that are thread-safe, but you have to evaluate those one by one

Comment: I mean the anonymous object initialisation of the final variable called handler. According to this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179793/are-kotlins-singletons-thread-safe

Objects, which are singletons, should be thread-safe, or am I interpreting this answer wrong?

Comment: After thinking about it and reading once more, it seems to only consider the initialisation of a Singleton class, not its access. I understood it in a way, that it will make the functions equivalent to synchronized in Java

Comment: @Igor yea, there is nothing so simple just yet :)